# How can I add a user name to a nexmo sms sent directly

Tags: laravel-livewire, vonage

I need to send an sms containing the user name, how can I do that in laravel please?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a generic question, so it's quite tricky to give an answer that will exactly what you want.

I've found a pretty decent tutorial that can guide you through sending an SMS using Vonage from a skeleton Laravel app here:

https://remotestack.io/send-sms-notification-to-mobile-phone-in-laravel-with-vonage/